# Nexus 7 (2012) Omni 6.0.1 Install failure

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, omnirom

I was trying to follow the instructions at http://www.teamandroid.com/2016/01/20/install-android-601-omnirom-nexus-7-2012-marshmallow-custom-rom/2/, which walk through downloading omni-6.0.1-20160115-grouper-HOMEMADE.zip, copying it to the root of the sdcard storage, and using clockwork recovery module to wipe the device and install it. I ran into a problem when trying to install the ZIP file downloaded from https://www.androidfilehost.com/?fid=24369303960685419 (which I was able to successfully select). An error is reported:

> ApplyParsedPerms: removexattr of system/bin/backuptool.sh to 0 failed:
>   Operation not supported on transport enpoint

Subsequently a Status 7 failure causes the installation to abort. The failure happened quite early (fortunately?) so I am still able to reboot and use the freshly wiped device, but I'd like to install this ROM because 2012 model Nexus 7s are notoriously unusable on Android 5.1.1, which is the latest OS formally available to them.

How do I get past this? The page I was following was supposedly specifically for the 2012 model of Nexus 7, which I have, so I thought this should have worked.

*Update:* Looking at the updater-script, I suspect this is the line that's failing, but I don't know enough about the design of this package or alternate ROMs to understand whether the problem is in the script or somewhere else:

```
set_metadata("/system/bin/backuptool.sh", "uid", 0, "gid", 0, "mode", 0755, "capabilities", 0x0);
```

Comment: You should use TWRP instead of cwm. Which 2012 nexus 7 is it? The Wi-Fi or the GSM (3g) version? The status 7 generally is a wrong device error.

Comment: @BoLawson I have the W-Fi model.

Comment: @BoLawson I figured out how to try TWRP, and it seemed to work better. Strange the method in the instructions didn't work.

Comment: The instructions are super old CWM is no longer in development. So, did you get it working with twrp? Or are you still getting status 7? Also here is the download from Omni's site. Probably better than third party.  http://dl.omnirom.org/grouper/

Comment: @BoLawson I got it working, but I can't get GApps installed because I only have 200 MB free on the system partition. I can't decide whether I should try stepping down again from micro to nano or if there's garbage that needs to be cleaned up on the system partition. Total system space is 655104 KB; Used is 451348 KB.

Comment: Omni is already quite light on `/system`, you will have to use a more basic set of GAPPS.

Comment: @AndyYan ~450 MB doesn't sound light to me. How can the regular Android OS fit all these apps in? I feel like there are some garbage files, not in Omni, but left behind in the system somehow. How do I see what's consuming space in the system partition?

Comment: The higher the Android version, the more space it takes. N7 2012 only got Android 5.1 max, and by then it already had to move most preinstalled apps (the non-essential ones) to `/data`.

Comment: @AndyYan I guess I should just go back to 4.x. Unfortunately, now that my device is rooted and flashed, system wipe doesn't replace clockwork or Omni, so I guess I have to use USB & Android toolkit to restore it. Hopefully 4.x is still there somewhere

Comment: If you are looking to return to stock (Google) 4.x, of course you need to flash the factory image from fastboot over again. I do suggest trying out some custom ROMs of the 4.x era, though, such as ParanoidAndroid (up to 3.99) or CM10.2 - those are the golden times of Android modding, and should offer you good speed without skimping on critical features (e.g. FSTRIM).

Answer (score 0):

Using TWRP 3.0.2 (with WugFresh Nexus Root Toolkit 2.1.9) instead of Clockwork worked.

Comment: Is there a particular version you used?

Comment: The version I used came with Wug's Nexus Root Toolkit, which I believe was at 2.1.9, or was downloaded as part of the installation process of that toolkit. I'll have to look it up when I get home to be more specific than that. I did have to download updated versions of a couple things while installing that so the version of the toolkit itself may be irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks. If you look it up again, please [edit] your post to incorporate your findings. That would be helpful.

Comment: @Firelord Version information added.